# How can I automatically re-size Draw.io's UML “Class” shape after adding new lines representing extra fields or methods?

Tags: uml, draw.io

It is tedious to extend the height and width of the class shape areas after added new fields or methods to the class representation.

Googling suggests ctrl-shft-y, / Arrange -> Autosize, but this does not appear to work as expected for "Class" shapes.  (It works fine on a regular rectangle).

Has anyone found a good way to add extra fields without manual overhead?

[Draw IO's class shape with new line not fitting once added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w94QZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

When text is written only in one line,
(when a new row is added)
try to select only that row (not the whole UML shape)
and go to Arrange > Autosize or press Ctrl+Shift+y
​
It should work well.

When the new row is added,
but the text is written in 2 or more lines,
please tick a "Formatted text" in Text tab (Format panel)
and then go to Arrange > Autosize or press Ctrl+Shift+y

It should increase the hight of the row.

If you have a problem with this, 
please vote for a Trello feature card I opened here:
https://trello.com/c/NSIxt85Y/424-support-autosize-for-uml-when-new-row-is-added-with-multi-line-text-change-height-correctly
cause there is a possibility that this feature should be improved.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand list shapes in Draw.io.

It's explained here https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000054082-adding-entries-in-uml-diagrams

Ctrl-Enter to 'add a new line' (clone a shape in the list) and enter to edit/rename that shape.